# If we know $\mathbb{Z}_{n}/ \mathbb{Z}_{m} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{k}$, can we conclude that $\mathbb{Z}_{n} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{m} \times \mathbb{Z}_{k} $?

Tags: group-theory

> If we know $\mathbb{Z}_{n}/ \mathbb{Z}_{m} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{k}$, can we conclude that $\mathbb{Z}_{n} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{m} \times \mathbb{Z}_{k} $?

I think not, but I can not find right counterexample. Any hint helps!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Counterexample:** $n =4, k=2 $.

Notably, $\Bbb Z_m \times \Bbb Z_k$ is cyclic if and only if $m, k$ are relatively prime.

Comment: It is perhaps notable that your isomorphism is equivalent to the statement that the short exact sequence $$0\to \Bbb Z _m \to \Bbb Z_n \to \Bbb Z_k \to 0$$ "splits".